# Symbol: Center of Mass (dowelpin)

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know of the symbol used for the center of mass in physics? Typically it is a circle with two quadrants shaded in. Unfortunately I can't find this in the standard LaTeX symbols PDF or on Detexify.

Is there a predefined command for this symbol or some other way I could get it?

Comment: In general, Scott Pakin's [LaTeX comprehensive symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) has a vast amount of symbols supported using various packages in LaTeX. See the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for more information.

Comment: ...sadly it's not in there... :( (yet?)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think it's available as a proper symbol, but you could use TikZ to draw it. By using the units `em` or `ex`, the symbol will scale corresponding to the surrounding text.

[image: dowel pin / center of mass / BMW symbol]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\centerofmass{%
    \tikz[radius=0.4em] {%
        \fill (0,0) -- ++(0.4em,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=90] -- ++(0,-0.8em) arc [start angle=270, end angle=180];%
        \draw (0,0) circle;%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

Center of Mass: \centerofmass

\Huge It scales! \centerofmass

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding the line `\fill [color=white] (0,0) -- ++(0,0.4em) arc [start angle=90,end angle=180] -- ++(0.8em,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=-90];%` before `\draw (0,0) circle;%` allows this to be put on a dark background nicer by filling in the "white" parts with white.

Comment: Adding the ‘white’ parts would be desirable, but when I do it, it forces the next line which follows the CoM symbol to be pushed further down. How might one fix this? @BeaumontTaz

Comment: Did you add `%` characters at the end of the lines in your new code, like I did in the code in my answer? Omitting those is commonly the cause for unwanted shifts.

Answer (score 7):

This can be generated via the [`stix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stix) symbols `\circleurquadblack`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stix,graphicx}
\newcommand{\centerofmass}{{\ooalign{$\circleurquadblack$\cr\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\circleurquadblack$}}}}

\begin{document}

$\circleurquadblack\ \centerofmass$

\end{document}
```

Comment: For those who are interested in moving the dowelpin around: `\node at (x,y) {$\centerofmass$};`

Comment: Unfortunately, using `stix` also changes the document font instead of just providing the wanted symbol.