# Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?

Tags: symbols

I looked all over but could not find anything. Is there a package out there that has a symbol/dingbat of a calculator? I know there probably isn't, but I've seen much stranger stuff out there before...

Comment: What will be the output size/usage of this?

Comment: about 1 cm, doesnt really have to be anything fancy, just wanted to know if one exists. i looked through every list of symbols i know about and didnt find anything. i just need a small calculator on a few pages of a document to be combined with a few other components of tikz and i was trying to avoid something external.

Comment: I think one might have to resort to "something external". For example, in general, what level of detail in terms of a calculator would one be interested in. Is "something external" an option?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are three different calculator symbols available at [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/calculator/):

[image]
<sub>Calculator symbols by The Noun Project and Scott Lewis, from The Noun Project.</sub>

The [first](http://thenounproject.com/noun/calculator/#icon-No804) [two](http://thenounproject.com/noun/calculator/#icon-No538) are published under *Creative Commons - Attribution (CC BY 3.0)*, the [third](http://thenounproject.com/noun/calculator/#icon-No879) one under *Creative Commons CC0 - No Rights Reserved*.

I think Martin Scharrer was at some point thinking about turning this fabulous icon collection into a package, but I don't know what the status on this is; there might have been some licensing issues.

You'll have to convert the SVG files into some format that LaTeX can work with, e.g. with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Then I recommend a `\newcommand` that embeds the images with a `height` in `ex`, so that it'll be scaled according to the current font size, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe} % Just for the demo image
\newcommand{\mysymbol}{\protect\includegraphics[height = 1.5ex]{example-image-a}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo \mysymbol\ bar}
{\Huge Bar baz \mysymbol!}

Foo bar baz \mysymbol\ baz bar foo.

{\tiny Baz bar \mysymbol?}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for the link! found something here that worked really well. thank you!

Comment: i thought i did it before, definitely did now...

Comment: @doncherry can you please put the code of calculator svg/converted format image with \newcommand that embeds the images with a `height` in `ex`? that would be great.

Comment: @doctorate See my edit.

Comment: @doncherry, +1 for the code, thanks a lot. It worked when converted to pdf not in svg format though, can it be directly from svg format?

Comment: @doctorate No, that’s not possible. For more on this topic, see [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099).

Answer (score 13):

My calculator :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[pdftex,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,matrix,backgrounds}%

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\grbl}{green!30!black}

\tikzstyle{ButtonRect}=[minimum width   = 1.2 cm,
                        minimum height  = 16 pt,
                        rounded corners = 8 pt] 

\tikzstyle{ButtonCircle}=[circle, minimum height   = 20pt]
\tikzstyle{ButtonEllipse}=[ellipse,
                           inner sep        = 0pt,
                           minimum height   = 16pt,
                           minimum width    = 1cm]


\newcommand*{\button}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[line width=.6pt,
      color=black,draw,#2,
      fill=#3,text=white](T){\footnotesize\textsf{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\tikzstyle{background rectangle}=
[ultra thick,draw=black,fill=SeaGreen!40,rounded corners=12pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=-1.5pt,outer sep=0pt,%
  text = white,show background rectangle]%

\matrix [matrix of  nodes](M1)
{\button{F1}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{Trace}}}{\grbl}
&\button{F2}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{Zoom}}}{\grbl}
&\button{F3}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{V-Window}}}{\grbl}
&\button{F4}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{Sketch}}}{\grbl}
&\button{F5}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{G-Solv}}}{\grbl}
&\button{F6}{ButtonCircle,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{G$\leftrightarrow$T}}}{\grbl}%
\\
 \button{\tiny SHIFT}{ButtonEllipse, minimum width = 30pt}{Goldenrod}
&\button{\tiny OPTN}{ButtonEllipse}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{\tiny VARS}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{PRGM}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{\tiny MENU}{ButtonEllipse,
   label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{SET UP}}}{PineGreen!60}
&&&\\

\button{\tiny ALPHA}{ButtonEllipse,
  label={[red]above:\tiny \textsf{\fboxsep 0pt \fbox{A}-LOCK}}}{red!70!black}%
  &\button{$x^2$}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60: \textsf{r}},%
label ={[red]120:\tiny \textsf{$\sqrt{\ }$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{$\bigwedge$}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60: \textsf{$\scriptstyle{\othertheta}$}},%
label ={[red]120:\tiny \textsf{$\root x \of{\ }$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{\tiny EXIT}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{QUIT}}}{RoyalBlue}
& &\\

 \button{\tiny X,$\othertheta$,T}%
             {ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{A}}}{RoyalBlue}%
&\button{log}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{B}},%
label ={[red]100:\tiny \textsf{$\text{10}^x$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{ln}{ButtonEllipse,label ={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{C}},%
label ={[red]120:\tiny \textsf{$\text{e}^x$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{sin}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{D}},%
label ={[red]100:\tiny \textsf{Asn}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{cos}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{E}},%
label ={[red]100:\tiny \textsf{Acs}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{tan}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{F}},%
label ={[red]100:\tiny \textsf{Atn}}}{RoyalBlue}
\\

 \button{a+{\tiny b/c}}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{G}},%
label ={[red]100:\tiny \textsf{d/c}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{F$\leftrightarrow$D}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{H}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{(}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{I}},%
label ={[red]120:\tiny \textsf{$\root\text{\tiny\textsf{3}} \of{\ }$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{)}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{J}},%
label ={[red]120:\tiny \textsf{$x^{ \text{\tiny\textsf{-1}}}$}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{\LARGE,}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{K}}}{RoyalBlue}
&\button{\large$\rightarrow$}{ButtonEllipse,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{L}}}{RoyalBlue}%
\\};

\matrix [matrix of  nodes,yshift=-2.5cm] at (M1.south)
{\button{\large 7}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{M}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 8}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{N}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 9}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{O}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\normalsize DEL}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{INS}}}{PineGreen!60}
&\button{\normalsize $\text{AC}^\text{\tiny /ON}$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{OFF}}}{PineGreen!60}
\\
 \button{\large 4}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{P}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 5}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{Q}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 6}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{R}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\Large $\times$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{\{ \hspace{14pt}S}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\Large $\div$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{\} \hspace{14pt}T}}}{\grbl}
\\
 \button{\large 1}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{U}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 2}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{V}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large 3}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{W}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large $+$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{[ \hspace{14pt}X}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large $-$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{] \hspace{14pt}Y}}}{\grbl}
\\
  \button{\large 0}{ButtonRect,label={[red]60:\tiny \textsf{Z}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\Huge .}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{= \hspace{8pt} SPACE}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\normalsize $\times\text{10}^x$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\normalsize  \textsf{$\pi$}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\large$( - )$}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{ANS}}}{\grbl}
&\button{\normalsize EXE}{ButtonRect,label={[red]90:\tiny \textsf{$\hookleftarrow$}}}{blue!50!black}
\\
};
\node[fill=lightgray,draw,ultra thick,text width=7cm,yshift=1cm,rounded corners,text=black] at (M1.north) {\(\sin(1)\)\\\hfill \(0.841470984\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Beautiful in a large scale but in the small version the details are not appreciated. :-)

Comment: @azetina It's possible because I created this picture without thinking to adapt it to a smaller size

Answer (score 11):

There are some awesome tikz calculators.  I though I will try something different, a small calculator icon that will fit in text, and rescale with the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\calculator{\tikz{
\node (c) [inner sep=0pt, draw, fill=black, anchor=south west]{\phantom{N}};
\begin{scope}[x=(c.south east),y=(c.north west)]
   \fill[white] (.1,.7) rectangle (.9,.9);
   \foreach \x in {.1, .33, .55, .79}{
   \foreach \y in {.1, .24, .38, .53}{
   \fill[white] (\x,\y) rectangle +(.11,.07);}}
\end{scope}
}}

\def\calctest#1{\noindent#1 This: \calculator\ is a calculator\par}
\begin{document}
\calctest{\tiny}

\calctest{\normalsize}

\calctest{\large}

\calctest{\Huge}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: Test of calculator icon]

Comment: That's a nice calculator icon. For making TikZ drawings scale with the font size, I generally like to just use `ex` and `em` units in the drawing. These will automatically scale with the surrounding text.See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23454/2552 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38758/2552

Comment: @Jake: I did consider using `ex` and `em`, however, I rejected it for this reason: `ex` is the **height** of the **lowercase** x and `em` is the **width** of an uppercase M. There is no way to get the **height** of an uppercase character.  Something like `1.75ex` could work well in one font, but will be too tall or too short in another.  That is OK for symbols like center of mass, but I wanted the calculator icon to have the same height as some typical uppercase letter, regardless of the font.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 8):

Since no font symbol of calculators exist (as far as I know), a colourful display is available from [OpenClipArt Library](http://openclipart.org/search/?query=calculator):

[image: OpenClipArt calculator]
[image: OpenClipArt calculator]
[image: OpenClipArt calculator]

All the images, unless stated otherwise, are in the [public domain](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) as downloadable SVG or (lossy) PNG images.

For inclusion of SVG images in LaTeX, see [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex) Alternatively, `pdflatex` supports native inclusion of PNG images.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\ab[1]{\adjustbox{
padding=0ex 0ex 0ex 0ex,
margin=-.5ex -.5ex -.5ex -.5ex, 
valign=M, 
cfbox=blue!50!black!50 2pt, 
margin=-.7ex -1ex -1ex -.7ex,
cfbox=blue!30!black!70 2.5pt, 
bgcolor=cyan!10!white,
margin=0ex .5ex 0ex .5ex,
}{#1}}


\newcommand\bb[1]{\adjustbox{
padding=0ex 0ex 0ex 0ex,
margin=-.5ex -.5ex -.5ex -.5ex, 
valign=M, 
cfbox=blue!50!black!50 2pt, 
margin=-.7ex -1ex -1ex -.7ex,
cfbox=blue!30!black!70 2.5pt, 
bgcolor=blue!20!black!60,
margin=0ex .5ex 0ex .5ex,
}{#1}}



\newcommand\kb[1]{
\ab{
\begin{minipage}[c][1em][c]{1em}
\centering#1
\end{minipage}
}}


\newcommand\calculator[1]{
\raisebox{.5ex}{\resizebox{#1}{!}{
\fboxrule=1.5pt
\bb{
\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{~}l}
\vspace{-.3cm}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bb{\fcolorbox{black!40!green!60}{black!30!green!30}{\Large ~~~~0.73122}}} & & \kb{\scriptsize ON} \\
\vspace{-.4cm}\\
\kb{1} & \kb{2} & \kb{3} & & \kb{+} \\
\kb{4} & \kb{5} & \kb{6} & & \kb{--}  \\
\kb{7} & \kb{8} & \kb{9} & & \kb{=}  \\
\end{tabular}
}}}}


\newcommand\calicon[1]{
\raisebox{.5ex}{\resizebox{#1}{!}{
\fboxrule=1.5pt

\bb{
\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{l@{}l@{}l@{}l@{~}l}
\vspace{-.3cm}\\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bb{\fcolorbox{black!40!green!60}{black!30!green!30}{\Large ~~~~~}}} & & \kb{\scriptsize } \\
\vspace{-.4cm}\\
\kb{} & \kb{} & \kb{} & & \kb{} \\
\kb{} & \kb{} & \kb{} & & \kb{}  \\
\kb{} & \kb{} & \kb{} & & \kb{}  \\
\end{tabular}
}}}}



\begin{document}


\noindent Poor man's calculators in poor \LaTeX{} without Ti\emph{k}Z: \\ 
\calicon{1em} \calculator{2em} 
\calicon{2em} \calculator{4em}
\calicon{4em} \calculator{8em}

\end{document}

\begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{c@{ }c}
$\div$&{--}\\
+&{\footnotesize M}\\
x&=\\
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
```

[image: MWE2]

A simpler coding with `tcolorbox` and `menukeys` packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96300/how-to-change-the-style-of-menukeys
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[>]{shadowedroundedkeys}
\begin{document}
Another poor man's calculator:

\begin{minipage}{14em}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,coltitle=blue!50!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tcolorbox}
[skin=widget,
boxrule=.3mm,
bottomrule=.75mm,rightrule=.75mm,
coltitle=red,
colframe=black!65!white,
colback=blue!15!white,
width=(.9\linewidth),before=\hfill,after=\hfill,
interior style={left color=gray!40!white,right color=blue!10!white},
adjusted title={
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[>]{roundedkeys}
\sffamily \keys{~~~~~~0.123456}    \hfill
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[>]{typewriterkeys}
  \keys{On}    }]
\keys{1} \keys{2} \keys{3}~~\keys{{+}}\keys{/} \\
\keys{4} \keys{5} \keys{6}~~\keys{--}\keys{{$\times$}} \\
\keys{7} \keys{8} \keys{9}~~\keys{=}\keys{M}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Lovely! Who needs zero! :-)

Answer (score 5):

This could be viewed ever so slightly as overkill ...

[image: TikZ calculator]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40095/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  positioning,
  backgrounds%
}
\colorlet{onepressed}{cyan}
\colorlet{sinpressed}{cyan}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,fill=cyan!50!white,minimum width=2em, minimum height=1.5em, text=red,node distance=5mm},show background rectangle,background rectangle/.style={draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2ex}]
\node[fill=onepressed] (1) {\(1\)};
\node[base right=of 1] (2) {\(2\)};
\node[base right=of 2] (3) {\(3\)};
\node[above=of 1] (4) {\(4\)};
\node[base right=of 4] (5) {\(5\)};
\node[base right=of 5] (6) {\(6\)};
\node[above=of 4] (7) {\(7\)};
\node[base right=of 7] (8) {\(8\)};
\node[base right=of 8] (9) {\(9\)};
\node[below=of 1] (0) {\(0\)};
\node[base right=of 9] (div) {\(\div\)};
\node[base right=of 6] (times) {\(\times\)};
\node[base right=of 3] (minus) {\(-\)};
\node[base right=of 0] (dot) {\(\cdot\)};
\node[base right=of dot] (equals) {\(=\)};
\node[base right=of equals] (plus) {\(+\)};
\node[fill=sinpressed,above=of 7] (sin) {\(\scriptstyle\sin\)};
\node[base right=of sin] (cos) {\(\scriptstyle\cos\)};
\node[base right=of cos] (tan) {\(\scriptstyle\tan\)};
\node[base right=of tan] (exp) {\(\scriptstyle\exp\)};
\node[minimum width=11.8em,above=of sin.north west,anchor=south west,fill=white,] (disp) {\(0.841470984807897\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Just in case anyone was interested, I happened to have that "lying around".  I use it in my lectures for introducing a topic on approximation by getting the students to try to imagine what the calculator is actually doing when one asks it to compute `sin(1)`.)

Comment: @PauloCereda also just happened to have a [calculator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2894186#2894186) handy...

Comment: @Werner: Andrew's calculator is way better than mine, it support *moar digitz*! `:)` Great answer, Andrew! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda The original was even *dynamic*: it is in a beamer presentation and as you advance screens, you see that first `1` is pressed and then `sin`, with the result shown in the display.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Awesome! Is it available for a preview? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda [Lecture 3 (Obviously) slides 6,7,8](http://mathsnotes.math.ntnu.no/mathsnotes/show/lecture+notes+2011)

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Fantastic! Another great entry for [What are your favourite TikZ/PGF answers?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers). `:)`

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Sweet, a Wiki in iTeX :)

Comment: @doncherry Are you referring to my course wiki?  If you think that's nice, [you ain't seen nothing yet](http://ncatlab.org).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Yes, I went through the slides of lecture one. But now I notice it's _itex_ and not _[iTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19079/what-on-earth-is-itex)_? I thought you were pulling a Knuth on your students.

Comment: @doncherry itex was around a few years before iTeX so it's an amusing name clash but nothing more (Charles' answer to the question you link to is relevant).

Comment: It would only be an overkill if you included some javascript to make it into [an actual working calculator](http://pragma-ade.com/show-dem-10.htm).

Answer (score 4):

A mono-button binary calculator.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\psset{fillstyle=solid}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,4)
    \psframe[fillcolor=gray,framearc=0.2](3,4)
    \rput(2.2,3.8){\psscalebox{.4}{\color{white}CASIO fx-666}}
    \rput(2.2,3.65){\psscalebox{.3}{\color{white}\it mono-button}}
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray](.5,3)(2.5,3.5)    
    \rput(1.5,3.25){1000010110}
    \pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @kissmyarmpit I think there is a problem with the design... is the one button also an on/off button? :-)

Answer (score 3):

As direct symbol of a calculator exist into the package `fontawesome5`: here there is a MWE with a screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faCalculator, {\large \faCalculator}, {\huge \faCalculator}
\end{document}
```

Using the classic `fontawesome` Web-Related Icons you can have another symbol of a calculator (using `pdflatex`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faCalculator, {\large \faCalculator}, {\huge\faCalculator}
\end{document}
```