# How to change the style of menukeys

Tags: formatting, menukeys

Maybe I am just stupid, but I don't manage to change the style of the output of [`menukeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys). The manual of this package lists in Section 4.2.1 some predefined styles. However, I can't find any hint of how to tell the package which style to use.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\begin{document}
Hello World!

\menu{File > Quit}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow this is really confusing in the way the manual is organized… it explains how to define styles and themes, but not how to just select an existing one as the default…

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `\renewmenumacro{<macro>}[<input sep>]{<style>}` -- see section 4.4.2 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{shadowedroundedkeys}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\menu{File > Quit}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, that is totally intuitive...not. What's wrong with `\usepackage[shadowroundedkeys]{menukeys}`? The current way lets you change the style during the document, but is that a real usecase? Thanks for digging that up!

Comment: @DBX12 I'm sorry if you're unsatisfied with the provided interface, but there are no plans to provide style-selection via package options (you take a look at a related discussion on Github: https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/46). I don't understand your "during the document" critique, though, of course you can still set the style for your entire document by specifying it once in the preamble with the provided interface (with the added bonus that the provided interface allows for more customisation than a predefined set of options).

Comment: First of all, sorry if my comment came as rude. I was annoyed about several things back then and this rather obscure way of configuring the style pushed me over the edge and made me more snarky than I wanted to be. For the "in the document": I meant you can have one style on page 1 and another style on page 2. Which is nice to have I guess, but I doubted the existence of a use case for it. I've read the github issue and now understand more why it was implemented that way. I would still prefer having a global package option, but understand why it would be hard to implement.