# menukeys package: using shadowed, rounded keys (style shadowedroundedkeys) globally

Tags: menukeys

I'm attempting to use the [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package to typeset keystrokes and menu selections. The comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96302/) (to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96300/)) states that one can set the style of all [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) objects globally, directly in `\usepackage`.

I tried the following (where I used `shadowedroundedkeys` in place of the "`shadowroundedkeys`" mistakenly used in the aforementioned comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96302/)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[os=win,shadowedroundedkeys]{menukeys}

\begin{document}

Keys: \keys{\ctrl+P} \newline
Menus: \menu{File > Quit}

\end{document}
```

But LaTeX gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Package xkeyval Error: `shadowedroundedkeys' undefined in families `tw@mk'.
```

How do I set the style of all [`menukeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) objects to `shadowedroundedkeys` globally? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Imho you are misunderstanding the comment, and the documentation certainly doesn't say anything about styles as package options.

Comment: One of the maintainers here (who is unfortunately less active than I'd wish I was...):The style-selection via package options is currently not planned and no documented feature, sorry. See the related issue on github: https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/46

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "all `menukeys` objects to `shadowedroundedkeys` globally"? Do you want `\menu` and `\keys` to give identical output? Please note that the `+` in the output between items in your list is part of the style, so if you'd set that style for `\menu` you'd get `File + Quit` (with the shadowed boxes around both `File` and `Quit`)...