# Symbol to represent a key

Tags: symbols

Does anybody knows a LaTeX command that represents a key, like this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at this:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics` if you have a graphic file with the drawing you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of [key pictograms available at the Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/key/#icon-No655), many (or all?) under some kind of permissive license. For some hints at how to use them, see [my answer to *Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40103/4012). Let me know if you need more guidance, I can expand that answer.

[image: keys]