# Add an exit sign / running person?

Tags: graphics, symbols, unicode

What is the simplest way to add a running person, similar to the one to the right in this image in my body text?

[image: exit sign, running man]

I cannot find any appropriate unicode glyph or LaTeX symbol. Do I need to include a picture or draw something with tikz?

Comment: You can either create a `TikZ` sign or use available, like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Fire_exit.svg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some exit signs found at [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/noun/exit/#icon-No20). See snapshot below:

[image]

I recommend reading the following answer to: [Symbol or dingbat of a calculator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40103/10898)

A previous answer suggests using Inkscape. You can also print it as a pdf and then import it as a picture by using the `graphicx` package and the command `\includegraphics{<image>}`. Remember that LaTeX also allows for the direct input of SVG files. You can read the following question [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/10898)

Answer (score 1):

You should search for an SVG-version of that picture (for sure on Wikipedia) and open it with Inkscape. Export it to Ti*k*Z path with [this extension](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/).

Then just insert this figure into your text (and scale it):

`bla blup \tikz ...; bla blup`