# Using an image as a dingbat in Xelatex

Tags: xetex

I currently have a large document that uses dingbats in section and subsection names to denote specific kinds of sections, currently using Pifont and a macro-ised *ding* command, for ease of changing the icon if required. I'm wondering if it's possible to use a PNG image as a custom dingbat for this purpose. An abridged, slimmed version of my code is shown below; the real document uses far more packages than this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Caladea}
%
\newcommand*{\wc}{\ding{71} }
%
\begin{document}
\section*{Section Foo Here}
\subsection*{\wc Subsection Bar Here}
\subsection*{\wc Subsection Foobar Here}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use images in xelatex, what exactly is the question?

Comment: `\newcommand*{\wc}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{myimage.png}}` ?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the \ding with another image, currently a PNG image, to allow for custom symbols to be placed in-line with text. The \wc command currently places a star symbol within the heading; I wish to use the PNG image instead of that star.

Comment: sure just use a definition as in my previous comment (using `graphicx` package)  this is no different from any other image inclusion is it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Caladea}
%
\newcommand*{\wc}{\includegraphics[height=1em]{house.png}}
%
\begin{document}
\section*{Section Foo Here}
\subsection*{\wc Subsection Bar Here}
\subsection*{\wc Subsection Foobar Here}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: uh, where's the image?  don't see it ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton it's my famous house image to the left of each **Subsection**

Comment: oh.  i'll have to get my monitor adjusted, i guess.  it's so faint that i can't really see it, even with my "computer" spectacles on.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed; also it turns out this question is a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40095/symbol-or-dingbat-of-a-calculator just my Google-fu wasn't up to scratch. Thank you, David, for your timely answer.